# How to make an icon URL based, Java

Tags: java, url, icons, imageicon

I've made an Java app that uses URL based images instead of file based images.
My question is, is there a way to get a URL image into an icon image?

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("icon.png").getImage());
```

That's how i would usually do an icon image but i tried:

```
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("i.imgur.com/<whatever>").getImage());
```

and it didn't seem to work, so is there a way to to it or is there atleast a way to get rid of the icon altogether without using a blank texture file?

Comment: `new ImageIcon(new URL("..."))` ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://some url/mypic.jpg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);

f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(image).getImage());
```

Comment: Thank you. If i don't accept the answer it's probably because i forgot, so yeah.

Comment: Actually it didn't work, i posted it into the wrong code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ImageIcon(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.net.URL-), but remember, this will load the icons in a background thread.

You may need to use a [`MediaTracker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html) if you want to know when the image is fully loaded.

I'd recommend using `ImageIO.read(URL)` instead, as this will return a fully realised image instead

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details